# How to extract and chop version string from file in bash

Tags: bash

I have a simple text file ./version containing a version number. Unfortunately, sometimes the version number in the file is followed by whitespaces and newlines like

```
1.1.3[space][space][newline]
[newline]
[newline]
```

What is the best, easiest and shortest way to extract the version number into a bash variable without the trailing spaces and newlines? I tried

```
var=`cat ./version | tr -d ' '`
```

which works for the whitespaces but when appending a `tr -d '\n'` it does not work.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still do not know why, but after deleting and recreating the version file this worked:

```
var=`cat ./version | tr -d ' ' | tr -d '\n'`
```

I'm confused... what can you do different when creating a text file. However, it works now.

Comment: You can do that with one call to tr by putting the space and newline inside square brackets: var=$(cat ./version | tr -d '[ \n]') – Dennis Williamson 0 secs ago  [delete this comment]

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo -e "1.1.1  \n\n" > ./version
$ read var < ./version
$ echo -n "$var" | od -a
0000000   1   .   1   .   1
0000005
```

Answer (score 2):

Pure Bash, no other process:

```
echo -e "1.2.3  \n\n" > .version

version=$(<.version)
version=${version// /}

echo "'$version'"
```

result: `'1.2.3'`

Answer (score 0):

I like the pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) version from [fgm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/974993/938111).

I provide this one-line [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) command to remove also other characters if any:

```
perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/'
```

The extracted version number is trimmed/stripped (no newline or carriage return symbols):

```
$> V=$( bash --version | perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/' )
$> echo "The bash version is '$V'"
The bash version is '4.2.45'
```

I provide more explanation and give other more sophisticated (but still short) one-line [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) commands in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19854164/938111).