# Extract version number from a string

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, sed

I have a string with components and version numbers:

`data-c(kuh-small1);divider-bin-1.4.4;divider-conf-1.3.3-w(1,16);storage-bin-1.5.4;storage-conf-1.5.0-w(1);worker-bin-4.5.1;worker-conf-4.4.1-c(kuh)-win2`

For a shell script, I need to extract the version number of the divider binary. So I need to yield:

`1.4.4`

What would be a good way to do this? with sed?

Comment: @fedorqui You are right! I think I wanted to point out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655276/sed-extract-version-number-from-string  I delete my first comment, and replace it by another.

Comment: See also a [similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655276/sed-extract-version-number-from-string) but about `sed` (there are some few answers based on commands `cut`, `perl` and `awk`).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Following [Kent's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16815516/1983854), this can work:

```
grep -Po '(?<=divider-bin-)\d.\d.\d'
```

and even better:

```
grep -Po '(?<=divider-bin-)[^;]+'
```

it greps from `divider-bin-` until it find the `;` character. This way any `NNN.NNN. ... . NNN` format will work (no matter how many blocks of `NN`).

#### Test:

```
$ echo "data-c(kuh-small1);divider-bin-1.4.4;divider-conf-1.3.3-w(1,16);storage-bin-1.5.4;storage-conf-1.5.0-w(1);worker-bin-4.5.1;worker-conf-4.4.1-c(kuh)-win2" | grep -Po '(?<=divider-bin-)[^;]+'
1.4.4
$ echo "data-c(kuh-small1);divider-bin-1.4;divider-conf-1.3.3-w(1,16);storage-bin-1.5.4;storage-conf-1.5.0-w(1);worker-bin-4.5.1;worker-conf-4.4.1-c(kuh)-win2" | grep -Po '(?<=divider-bin-)[^;]+'
1.4
```

Comment: how to grep it until it finds the second `;` character?

Comment: @KoustuvSinha I would need some sample input to know what you are referring to.

Comment: like I have a similar requirement, where I put the stop character as `\s` to get a version number, say 3.2.1 Now, i want to get only upto 3.2. Using stop character as `.` i can get only upto 3

Comment: @KoustuvSinha `grep -Po '(?<=divider-bin-)\d.\d'` should make it. Otherwise, ask a new question providing more details.

Comment: just living a comment because it happened to me but if -P is not available in your grep version you can go with the sed, aswer to my question:

"Then use sed, sed -n 's/.*(version) = "\([0-9.]*\).*/\1/p'. See demo. – Wiktor Stribiżew Oct 1 at 9:23"
https://ideone.com/Niylke

Comment: It doesn't work. It gives: ```invalid option -- P```

Comment: @MA1 are you using GNU Grep?

Comment: @fedorqui I'm using (BSD grep, GNU compatible). 
Is there any other ways to accomplish this without installing extra tools?

Comment: @MA1 you need GNU grep to have this answer work. Otherwise, you can use Perl or sed, as recommended by other answers here.

Answer (score 7):

### This general answer should work in all cases

I use one of these three one-line [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) commands depending on the expected input string:

1. The input string always contain one single version

   ```
    perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/'
   ```
2. To extract several versions (several lines)

   ```
    perl -pe 'if(($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/){$_.="\n"}'
   ```
3. To extract one single version (the first one) in all cases

   ```
    perl -pe 'if(($v)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/){print"$v\n";exit}$_=""'
   ```

---

1. The simplest

---

The first command line do not embed the final newline:

```
> gcc --version | perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/'
5.3.1

> bash --version | perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/'
4.2.46

> perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/' <<< 'A2 33. Z-0.1.2.3.4..5'
0.1.2.3.4

> uname -a | perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/'
3.10.0

> lsb_release | perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/'
4.1
```

Store the version within a shell variable:

```
> v=$( gcc --version | perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/' )
> echo "GCC version is '$v'"
GCC version is '5.3.1'
```

But fails for multi version numbers:

```
> gwenview --version
Qt: 4.8.5
KDE Development Platform: 4.14.8
Gwenview: 4.10.4

> gwenview --version | perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/'
4.8.54.14.84.10.4
```

2. Extract one version per line

---

```
> gwenview --version | perl -pe 'if(($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/){$_.="\n"}' 
4.8.4
4.14.8
4.10.4

> mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.11.0-13-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

> mvn --version | perl -pe 'if(($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/){$_.="\n"}'
3.0.4
1.7.0
3.11.0
```

3. Extract the first version only

---

```
> gwenview --version | perl -pe 'if(($v)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/){print"$v\n";exit}$_=""'
4.8.5
```

Create an alias:

```
> alias extractor='perl -pe '\''if(($v)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/){print"$v\n";exit}$_=""'\'''
```

or if you use a recent [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
> alias extractor=$'perl -pe \'if(($v)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/){print"$v\n";exit}$_=""\''

> v=$( mvn --version | extractor )
> echo "The maven version is '$v'"
The maven version is '3.0.4'
```

Comment: 'client_release/7.18/7.18.0/'. Not extracting all version in it

Answer (score 2):

sed can handle this easily....

```
string="ata-c(kuh-small1);divider-bin-1.4.4;divider-conf-1.3.3-w(1,16);storage-bin-1.5.4;storage-conf-1.5.0-w(1);worker-bin-4.5.1;worker-conf-4.4.1-c(kuh)-win2"

echo $string | sed "s/^.*divider-bin-\([0-9.]*\).*/\1/"
1.4.4
```

There are a few other things you can do to tighten it up... such as stop grabbing the version number when you reach the ";"

```
sed "s/^.*divider-bin-\([^;]*\).*/\1/"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use perl:

```
perl -wne '/divider-bin-(.+?);/ and print "$1\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n "s/.*;divider-bin-\([0-9][^;]*\);.*/\1/p"
```

infos is between `;divider-bin-` and next `;` and start with a digit. This is to ensur that no `Other-divider-bin-` or `divider-bin-and-hex-` will interfere with your request. Also, return empty string if not find.
to be exhaustif (assuming version is only digit and dot)

```
sed -n "s/.*;divider-bin-\([0-9.]\{1,\}\)\([^0-9.;][^;]*\)*;.*/\1/p"
```