# how to grep everything between single quotes?

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I am having trouble figuring out how to grep the characters between two single quotes .

I have this in a file
`version: '8.x-1.0-alpha1'`

and I like to have the output like this (the version numbers can be various):

`8.x-1.0-alpha1`

I wrote the following but it does not work:

`cat myfile.txt | grep -e 'version' | sed 's/.*\?'\(.*?\)'.*//g'`

Thank you for your help.

Addition: 
I used the sed command `sed -n "s#version:\s*'\(.*\)'#\1#p"`
I also like to remove 8.x-  which I edited to `sed -n "s#version:\s*'8.x-\(.*\)'#\1#p"`.

This command only works on linux and it does not work on MAC. How to change this command to make it works on MAC?

`sed -n "s#version:\s*'8.x-\(.*\)'#\1#p"`

Comment: Note that `cat | grep | sed` is largely pointless and can just be `sed pattern myfile.txt`. What format is this file in? My guess is sed is the wrong tool for this.

Comment: Your shell is ‘eating’ your quotes; `sed` doesn’t get to see them.

Comment: See [Extract version number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817646/extract-version-number-from-a-string).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings)

Comment: @Kwright02: that "regex" only quotes the parens. the `.*` is unquoted and will be handled/expanded by the shell

Comment: @Kwright02 You can’t escape single quotes within single quotes like that.

Comment: I like to use the sed command. `sed -n "s#version:\s*'\(.*\)'#\1#p" myfile.txt` How can I remove the `8.x-` from my output.

Comment: Don't add requirements in comments. If your question doesn't state what you really want then fix your question. You did just waste several peoples time trying to help you with a question that isn't really what you want to please make sure to get it right this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this: `sed -n "s#version:\s*'\(.*\)'#\1#p" myfile.txt`. This avoids the redundant `cat` and `grep` by finding the "version" line and extracting the contents between the single quotes.

Explanation:

the `-n` flag tells sed not to print lines automatically. We then use the `p` command at the end of our sed pattern to explicitly print when we've found the version line.

Search for pattern: `version:\s*'\(.*\)'`

- `version:\s*` Match "version:" followed by any amount of whitespace
- `'\(.*\)'` Match a single `'`, then capture everything until the next `'`

Replace with: `\1`; This is the first (and only) capture group above, containing contents between single quotes.

Comment: I tried this command (replacing the `:` with `=`) with a line as follows:
`version='0.1.2',`.

The output was:
`0.1.2,`, meaning that your suggested command does not precisely keep only what's between single quotes

Comment: It prints everything in the line of `version=`, after that and without the `'`

Comment: Thank you, this works nicely to get a __version__ variable from a python file, e.g. to be used in CI: `sed -n "s#__version__ =\s*'\(.*\)'#\1#p" version.py` will extract `0.20.9` from version.py with a line `__version__ = '0.20.9'`

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to have that information from the file, and only that you can quickly do:

```
awk -F"'" '/version/{print $2}' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo "version: '8.x-1.0-alpha1'" | awk -F"'" '/version/{print $2}'
8.x-1.0-alpha1
```

**How does this work?**

An awk program is a series of pattern-action pairs, written as:

```
condition { action }
condition { action }
...
```

where `condition` is typically an expression and `action` a series of commands.

1. **`-F "'"`:** Here we tell [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to define the field separator `FS` to be a <single quote> `'`. This means the all lines will be split in fields `$1`, `$2`, ... ,`$NF` and between each field there is a `'`. We can now reference these fields by using `$1` for the first field, `$2` for the second ... etc and this till `$NF` where `NF` is the total number of fields per line.
2. **`/version/{print $2}`:** This is the condition-action pair.

   - condition: `/version/`:: The condition reads: *If a substring in the current record/line matches the regular expression `/version/` then do `action`*. Here, this is simply translated as *if the current line contains a substring `version`*
   - action: `{print $2}`:: If the previous condition is satisfied, then print the second field. In this case, the second field would be what the OP requests.

There are now several things that can be done.

1. Improve the `condition` to be `/^version :/ && NF==3` which reads _If the current line starts with the substring `version :` **and** the current line has 3 fields then do `action`
2. If you only want the first occurance, you can tell the system to `exit` immediately after the find by updating the action to `{print $2; exit}`

Comment: Nice. To reduce false positive matches, I would use `$1 == "version: " {print $2}`

Answer (score 5):

I'd use GNU grep with pcre regexes:

```
grep -oP "version: '\\K.*(?=')" file
```

where we are looking for "version: '" and then the `\K` directive will forget what it just saw, leaving `.*(?=')` to match up to the last single quote.

Answer (score 2):

When your only want to look at he quotes, you can use `cut`.

```
grep -e 'version' myfile.txt | cut -d "'" -f2
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep` can almost do this alone:

```
grep -o "'.*'" file.txt
```

But this may also print lines you don't want to: it will print all lines with 2 single quotes (`'`) in them. And the output still has the single quotes (`'`) around it:

```
'8.x-1.0-alpha1'
```

But `sed` alone can do it properly:

```
sed -rn "s/^version: +'([^']+)'.*/\1/p" file.txt
```